# Merge Data on Two Variables With Override in R

Tags: r, merge

I have two datasets of results from competitions, each of which have the variables "Name", "School", and "Points."

I want to merge these two datasets in R by "Name" and "School", because some students have attended both competitions. However sometimes the schools are spelled differently from tournament to tournament, so I need the merge to override the different spelling (default to the first spelling).

Thoughts on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: `agrep` maybe, an example would help

Answer (score 0):

If you can collect all possible misspellings for schools like this:

```
data.frame(
  possible_spelling = c("a school", "a skool", "b schol", "b skol"),
  actual_spelling = c("a school", "a school", "b school", "b school")
)
```

Then you can merge that into both datasets and then join by actual_spelling

Do this if you want to generate a list of possible school spellings:

```
library(dplyr)
dataset_1 %>% select(school) %>%
  bind_rows(dataset_2 %>% select(school) %>%
  distinct %>%
  arrange(school) %>%
  write.csv(row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: I can't predict all the possible ways of writing the school, nor do I have the full school list (we have many tournaments over the year and many schools.) I think my original question was confusing- basically I need the merge to fill in data for School  if data didn't already exist, but to leave it alone if the School is already added. Hope that clears it up?

Comment: See the edit above for generating a list of all possible spellings. Then, in an excel, make one column for possible spellings and one column for actual spelling, then read back in as a csv.